# Re-render a dynamic Grid

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have troubles to re-render a grid that I create dynamically

My grid (VertGrid) is declared in my XAML and it is used as container for my vertical grid

XAML:

```
<Grid x:Name="VertGrid"   HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                          VerticalAlignment="Top"
                          SizeChanged="VertGrid_SizeChanged" />
```

In the code-behind, I create all the rows, combobox, textblocks, bindings... to bind with my ViewModel. 
The problem is, I want to reset the size of my grid when some events happen (to have the ActualWidth and ActualHeight at 0) because an another graph component should be adapt depending on the width of the VertGrid dynamically.

For example:

```
private void VertGrid_SizeChanged(object sender, SizeChangedEventArgs e)
{
   InitGrid();
   UpdateGraph();
}
```

I tried to remove all the UIElement in the grid, UpdateLayout, InvalidateVisual... Nothing resets the ActualWidth and the ActualHeight to 0 and I can't help myself to find out why. :(

Thanks for your help !

Comment: `Visibility="Collapsed"` should exclude Grid from layout

Comment: You have HorizontalAlignment="Stretch", so your grid will resize its width to its parent. To manipulate the width of your grid, you'll need to remove this line and explicitly set/bind Width property instead. As @ASh said, setting visibility to collapsed instead may work too.

Comment: Thanks for your answers, indeed the actualwidth is set to 0 when I collapse the grid... but it retakes his old value when I re-set it to Visible instead of take the width depending on his new content. I deleted the HorizontalAlignment too, nothing changed

Comment: "Deleting" the HorizontalAlignment attribute from the Grid element in the XAML won't help since the default value is Stretch. You should set it to Left if you don't want the Grid to stretch to fill the available width. <Grid ... HorizontalAlignment="Left">

Comment: Thank ! Yes, the solution was to set the HorizontalAlignment to Left and constrain the grid with an explicity width :) thanks for your answers !